# Inventory update

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to update inventory using Excel Files. In Workbook 1, column A I have a SKU to identify each product. In workbook 2, Column A is a matching SKU (not in the same order as Workbook 1) Column B has an inventory amount. I need to match Workbook 1, column A SKUs with Workbook 2 column A SKUs, and then add Column B inventory amounts (Workbook2) into Workbook 1. What would be the formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Workbook 1 Column B, you can try this formula:

```
=INDEX('[Worbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!B:B,MATCH(A1,'[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,0))
```

Then drag the formula to other cells

Answer (score 0):

*You can try below shown method:*

[image]

- Formula in cell B36 (in Workbook 1):

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX('[Worbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!E$36:E$39,MATCH(A36,'[Worbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!D$36:D$39,0),1),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- Formula wrapped with IFERROR traps the error and replace #N/A with Blanks.
- In this part `MATCH(A36,'[Worbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!D$36:D$39,0),1)`,, `1` represents column position.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.